# Convert a HTML5 canvas to PDF using Tcl

Tags: tcl

I want to save a base64 String retrieved from a HTML5 canvas via Javascript to a PDF file using Tcl.

I get the base 64 SDtring from the Canvas via JS: `let data = chart.getImage('stream').data;`
Meanwhile i saved this base64 Data in a File for testing. In my Tcl Script i load this File and try to convert this with the package **pdf4tcl**.

```
#! /bin/env tclsh

# import Tcl (optional) but makes script more portable
package require Tcl

# import pdf4tcl
lappend auto_path "C:/Users/ - deleted for privacy ^^ -"
package require pdf4tcl

# Read demo File (contains base64 encoded canvas)
set fp [open "singerGraph.txt" r]
set canvas_data [read $fp]
close $fp


# create a pdf object
pdf4tcl::new mypdf -paper a4 -margin 15mm
mypdf startPage

# this command doesnt work
# mypdf putRawImage $image_data 60 20 -height 40

# write pdf to a file
mypdf write -file mypdf.pdf
mypdf destroy
```

The putRawImage method yields

```
 instead
    while executing
"binary format H* $row"
    (class "::pdf4tcl::pdf4tcl" method "putRawImage" line 88)
    invoked from within
"mypdf putRawImage $canvas_data 60 20 -height 40"
    (file "base64ToPdf.tcl" line 28)
```

But i think this is the wrong command anyway...

For a simple test, this base 64 might be sufficient

```
data =  "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAUAAAAFCAIAAAACDbGyAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAAlwSFlzAAALEwAACxMBAJqcGAAAAAd0SU1FB9oMCRUiMrIBQVkAAAAZdEVYdENvbW1lbnQAQ3JlYXRlZCB3aXRoIEdJTVBXgQ4XAAAADElEQVQI12NgoC4AAABQAAEiE+h1AAAAAElFTkSuQmCC";
```

However my Data starts with : `data:application/octet-stream;base64,` but i don't know if that's important or not. The test data is too long to paste here.

Can someone lead me in the right direction. So i can convert this data into a PDF or even a PNG would be sufficient for now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was able to get a

1. PNG from my base64 String
2. then get that PNG onto a PDF
3. and save the PDF as a file

Since I am very new to Tcl this code might be awful but for now, it's a good starting point.

```
#! /bin/env tclsh

package require base64
package require Img

# import pdf4tcl
lappend auto_path "C:/Users/ *username* /Documents/Tcl-TK"
package require pdf4tcl

# Read demo File   (with removed prefix: [data:application/octet-stream;base64,])
set fp [open "singerGraph.txt" r]
set canvas_data [read $fp]
close $fp

# Create PNG Image
set data [binary decode base64 $canvas_data]
set img [image create photo imgobj -data $data -format PNG]

# Display Image
puts $img
pack [label .myLabel]
.myLabel configure -image imgobj 

# create a pdf object
pdf4tcl::new mypdf -paper a4 -margin 15mm
mypdf startPage

# add Image to PDF 
set img_handle [mypdf addRawImage [imgobj data]]
mypdf putImage $img_handle 15 15 -width 210

# write pdf to a file
mypdf write -file heureka.pdf
mypdf destroy
```

@DonalFellows Thank you for your help. I need to adjust that `decodeImage` function for my needs but you brought me a step further.

Answer (score 1):

You need to strip the metadata (i.e., the prefix `data:image/png;base64,`) before decoding that string.

Here's a procedure to do that:

```
proc decodeImage {string} {
    if {[regexp {^data:image/(\w+);base64,(.*)$} $string type data]} {
        # DEBUG: puts "we have image data of type $type"
        return [binary decode base64 $data]
    } elseif {[regexp {^data:image/(\w+),(.*)} $string type data]} {
        # DEBUG: puts "we have image data of type $type"
        return $data
    } elseif {[regexp {^[0-9a-fA-F]+$} $string]} {
        # Looks like hexadecimal data...
        return [binary decode hex $string]
    }
    # It's in some other format. There's like a zillion of them so…
    error "unrecognised format"
}
```

I suspect that's not enough, and that the data you're embedding is supposed to be hex-encoded (because of that `binary format`), but I don't know for sure as that might be a fallback for when it doesn't recognise the raw data.

Comment: Thank you, you definitely got me one step closer. When trying to create the image I `get couldn't recognize image data`, so I am going to look up some "base64 formats"